# Hyperlink in a footnote containing a %

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, catcodes

I want to write a link to a webpage into a footnote. Using the `hyperref` package, this works fine unless I have a `%` symbol in the link. This is the MWE (which is not working):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}               % clickable links

\author{Hans Wurst}
\title{Some amazing title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
An abstract with some footnote\footnote{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{tex.stackexchange}} which should contain a link to a webpage. Unfortunately, a link in a footnote\footnote{\href{https://somepage.com/Documents%20}{bla}} containing a \% does not work.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `\href` is in a footnote.  Therefore, the catcode of `%` is fixed as 14 when `\footnote` absorbs its argument, before `\href` can do its own catcode magic inside the footnote.  By then, it is too late to undo the damage.

Solution.  Change the catcode of `%` to 12 before the footnote invocation (and change it back afterwards).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}               % clickable links

\author{Hans Wurst}
\title{Some amazing title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
An abstract with some footnote\footnote{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}
  {tex.stackexchange}} which should contain a link to a webpage. Unfortunately, 
  a link in a footnote\catcode`\%=12 \footnote
  {\href{https://somepage.com/Documents%20On%20file}{bla}} \catcode`\%=14
  containing a \% does not work.% A COMMENT??

\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution and the clear explanation, I just learned something new :)

Comment: @Alf You are welcome.  Catcodes provide some of the weirdest yet most fascinating aspects of TeX.